# How to prevent data to re-rende inside Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have FutureBuilder Widget like this code

```
Future getJam()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String dataIn= prefs.getString("clock");
    return dataIn;
  }

  Widget defaultClock() {
    print(clockIn);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getJam(),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.hasData ) {
              print(snap.data);
          return Text(snap.data);
        }
        else{return Text("false");}
      },
    );
  }
```

the problem is.... the data always run this first`else{return Text("false");}` and then

```
if (snap.hasData ) {
              print(snap.data);
          return Text(snap.data);
        }
```

is there a way to prevent that problem?

Comment: I suppose in your code: first time `else` block is shown and re-rendering takes place and `if` block is shown. This is not a problem but the exact design philosphy behind `FutureBuilder`. When some part of data will be available in future and while we are waiting for that data to come we shown the user some other info. After the data is available to us the `FutureBuilder` automatically shows the new data without triggering a re-render because the `FutureBuilder` is the one that triggers the re-render but only the part inside the `FutureBuilder` is re-rendered instead of the complete screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check prefs.getString("clock") contains any value or not. if it does not contain any value then it will return null and because of that you are getting false text only.

replace following line in your code which take care of null.

```
String dataIn = prefs.getString("clock") ?? 'default';
```

**Updated:**

I think you want to check connection state, if connection state is done then you can check snap contain data or not.

if connection state is not complete then you can show anything like progress inidcator.

```
if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snap.hasData) {
                    print(snap.data);
                    return Text(snap.data);
                  } else {
                    return Text("false");
                  }
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
              },
```

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding here...prefs.getString("clock") contains a value... so when I run my code... The text always show ```false``` first and then ```Text(snap.data)```... so what I mean  is.. is there a way, so that my code always run Text(snap.data) first

Answer (score 1):

store your future like this on initState or build function,

```
Future _getJam = getJam(); // This will help prevent unnecessary re-render.
```

and use it like this,

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _getJam,
    builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return Text('false');
        if (snap.hasError) return Text("Something went wrong.");
        return Text(snap.data);
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understood right, but if you want to run the code (first) then change your if statement.

Your if statement checks if data (snap.data) are already arrived or not on building time. That's the correct way of using Futurebuilder.